# I get an error when database is connecting

Tags: c#, database, winforms, visual-studio-2013, database-connection

I have a probleme with the database.
On my computer is working well but when i try to run it from other computer is not working.

This is connection string:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\OlxBotDataBase.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
```

I try to put database in %appdata% folder, but is not working or maybe i'm doing it wrong.

This is the error:
[image]

**EDIT:** I installed sql server, but now i get this error:
 [image]

Comment: Your *other* computer either don't have sql server installed or Instance of the sql server different.

Comment: Did you install the LocalDB bits on the target machine?

Answer (score 0):

you can change permission for mdf and log file so that it can be accessed through your application

Comment: permission is set to full control

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

I installed sql server express and atached the database and i modify connectionString like this:

```
connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Database=OlxBotDataBase;Integrated Security=True");
```

But i want to know if there is any way to automaticaly add database.